# Reproducing entire slicing configurations in Slic3r

Tags: slicing, slic3r

3D printing is often an iterative process and I frequently find myself wanting to re-slice an STL I've already printed, but with just one setting tweaked. The problem is, unless I have left Slic3r open with the STL still loaded, I struggle to remember the exact combination of Print Settings, Filament Settings & Printer Settings I used for a previous print.

Am I missing something, or do I need to be meticulous in manually noting down every single setting? Feels like there should be a way for the computer to handle this for me.

Comment: Did you check the generated gcode? There is a section at the end with the settings used to generate it if thats what you are after.